# Stop IntelliJ run console from resseting settings (wrapping lines)

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ Idea for Rust and each time I run my code the settings in the *run console* reset (e.g. font size resets to default, and line wrapping turns on)

I've tried turning it off here but it just resets it each time I run my code

[image]

I can't find any settings for this either (although my settings seem to be misbehaving too)

I'm using Idea community 2022.2.4

Comment: Does the issue occur in the latest release version as well? Does the issue occur with the default settings? File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings...: https://i.imgur.com/kbrkC7w.png.

Comment: @CrazyCoder yes I tried it on 2022.3.3 and with default settings and it still had this issue

Comment: Is it specific to Rust or does it happen with any Run console?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I tried it now with Java and it resets the font size (which I'm ok with) but doesn't reset not the line wrapping (which is what I want). I also realized that I no longer have a default font size for the console in my settings even though I remmember it being there before

Comment: Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | Console Font | Size. Do you mean that you change the font size there and then it gets reset? At what point is it reset?

Comment: Oh now I found it... IDK why I couldn't see it before.. It's set there to 17 and it resets (after changing it with control+scroll) to 17 each time I run my code (but that doesnt bother me) what bothers me is the line wrapping is turned on

Comment: Changing the font with control+scroll is temporary and will not persist. It's by design. Disabling line wrapping in the run console should stick, and it does stick for me. I restarted the IDE, ran a file again, and line wrapping remained disabled.

Comment: Restarting my computer had fixed it for a bit but it's now back to not working (restarting again doesn't help) (and I'm using Idea 2023.1 now)